# Click event works with jQuery but not with Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript

AddEventListener is not working for me. This is what I have tried:

```js
const mtRemoveKeywords = document.querySelectorAll('.mt-remove-keyword');
for (let mtRemoveKeyword of mtRemoveKeywords) {
  mtRemoveKeyword.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        alert('JS');
  });
}
```

I do not get an error message, so nothing happens. I guess this is because the selector is a dynamic element. I also tried it with `windows.onload` but that didn't help. The weird thing is that I have tried it with jQuery and that worked!

```js
$(document).on('click', '.mt-remove-keyword', function() {
     alert('jQuery');
});
```

Why is it not working with Vanilla JS?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v3wad075/8/)

Comment: Note your jquery version is using a delegated event listener, the event is actually attached to the document not the individual elements. That is why it works as the events triggered bubble up to the document.

Comment: It seems that those elements are not present in the page at the moment your vanilla JS is running.